# Conditional calculation of Text field value based on another text field value using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, python-parser, querystring

In ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 I created a new field to explain some zoning codes in an attribute Table. I basically want the new field "Zone" to have a string value based on the field "Zoning".

For example if the "Zoning" field value is "AG" then the corresponding "Zone" field should be "Agricultural".

I can do this easily in an Excel Sheet and bring it back to a Layer by a join, But I really want to know if there is a way to do this either with Python or VBScript using the Field Calculator.

The code may be something similar top the one below.

```
If [Zoning] = "AG" Then 
[Zone]= "Agricultural"
```

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21916/using-conditional-statements-in-field-calculator?rq=1 http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52930/arc-10-python-shp-attributes-usings-fields-to-populate-other-fields-if-then?rq=1 http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52930/arc-10-python-shp-attributes-usings-fields-to-populate-other-fields-if-then?rq=1

Comment: Have you looked at using subtypes?  That might be another way of doing it.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005r00000001000000

Answer (score 2):

This should be fairly simple to do using the Python parser in Field Calculator.  Right click on the [Zone] field header and select Field Calculator.

In your Pre-Logic Code block, put something like:

```
def zone_type(zone):
    if zone == "AG"
        type = "Agricultural"
    elif zone == "other zone"
        type = "other type"
    elif zone == "other zone" # Repeat for each additional zone
        type = "other type"   # and zone type
    return type
```

In your other code block, you should have something like:

```
Zone = zone_type(!Zoning!)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried several times (few combination of different syntax) but it is not working

Comment: Here is my Code ( pre-logic and code block)     def zone_type( zone ):
    if zone == "AG"
        type = "Agricultural"
    elif zone == "C1"
        type = "Neighborhood Commerciall"
    elif zone == "MF-1" 
        type = "Multi Family"   # and zone type
    return type


zone_type(!Zoning!)

Comment: The links provided by @afalciano are useful resources as well.